# How can I swap items in a vector, slice, or array in Rust?

Tags: rust

My code looks like this:

```
fn swap<T>(mut collection: Vec<T>, a: usize, b: usize) {
    let temp = collection[a];
    collection[a] = collection[b];
    collection[b] = temp;
}
```

Rust is pretty sure I'm not allowed to "move out of dereference" or "move out of indexed content", whatever that is. How do I convince Rust that this is possible?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There is a [`swap` method defined for `&mut [T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap). Since a `Vec<T>` can be [mutably dereferenced](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) as a `&mut [T]`, this method can be called directly:

```
fn main() {
    let mut numbers = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("before = {:?}", numbers);
    numbers.swap(0, 2);
    println!("after = {:?}", numbers);
}
```

To implement this yourself, you have to write some unsafe code. [`Vec::swap` is implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.13.0/src/libcore/slice.rs#L429-L437) like this:

```
fn swap(&mut self, a: usize, b: usize) {
    unsafe {
        // Can't take two mutable loans from one vector, so instead just cast
        // them to their raw pointers to do the swap
        let pa: *mut T = &mut self[a];
        let pb: *mut T = &mut self[b];
        ptr::swap(pa, pb);
    }
}
```

It takes two raw pointers from the vector and uses [`ptr::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.swap.html) to swap them safely.

There is also a [`mem::swap(&mut T, &mut T)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) when you need to swap two distinct variables. That cannot be used here because Rust won't allow taking two mutable borrows from the same vector.

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned by @gsingh2011, the accepted answer is no longer good approach. With current Rust this code works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let mut numbers = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("before = {:?}", numbers);
    numbers.swap(0, 2);
    println!("after = {:?}", numbers);
}
```

[try it here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%20%20%20%20fn%20main()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20numbers%20%3D%20vec!%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22before%20%3D%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20numbers)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20numbers.swap(0%2C%202)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22after%20%3D%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20numbers)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: I've updated the other answer, so this is now redundant.