# Swap two elements in a vector in rust

Tags: rust

I want to swap two elements in a vector.
I wrote this function to swap elements, but it gives it gives an error.

```rust
fn swap<T>(arr: &mut Vec<T>, i: usize, j: usize) {
    let temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<T>`
 --> src/quick_sort.rs:2:16
  |
2 |     let temp = arr[i];
  |                ^^^^^^
  |                |
  |                move occurs because value has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |                help: consider borrowing here: `&arr[i]`
```

Comment: There is no way to write this without unsafe code, but thankfully there's https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap

Comment: @BallpointBen That's not true, you could do it with `split_at_mut` as well.

Comment: @orlp but internally `split_at_mut` also has some `unsafe` code, exactly for this reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I swap items in a vector, slice, or array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531963/how-can-i-swap-items-in-a-vector-slice-or-array-in-rust)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't added any constraints to T, your generic `swap<T>()` function needs to be able to work for any type T. Importantly, it needs to be able to work for types even if they don't implement the [Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait, therefore the assignment operator (`=`) performs a move. You can't move the value out of the vector like this, or this would invalidate the vector. Of course, you plan to fix up the vector so that it is valid again, but the compiler doesn't see the big picture here, it only sees the initial move as invalidating the vector, and therefore is illegal.

To implement swap here, you would need to use `unsafe` code. However, swap is a common problem, so the Rust standard library exposes functions to do this so you don't have to ([std::mem::swap()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) or [Vec::swap()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap) as @Locke mentioned).

Alternatively, you could specify that your swap function only works for types which implement the Copy trait, like so:

```
fn swap<T: Copy>(arr: &mut Vec<T>, i: usize, j: usize) {
    let temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

However, there is no advantage to writing your own swap over std::mem::swap().

Comment: I don't see how `std::mem::swap` could be used here without unsafe code (to get mutable references to both `&mut arr[i]` and `&mut arr[j]`).

Comment: Good point, probably would be better to not even mention `std::mem::swap()` here.

Answer (score 2):

You are in luck, the implementers thought that people may want an easy way of swapping elements and added [`Vec::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap). This method is also implemented with slices. If you want to swap the values for two mutable references you can use [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html).

```rust
fn swap<T>(arr: &mut Vec<T>, i: usize, j: usize) {
    arr.swap(i, j);
}
```

Alternatively while it is a bit of a pain to do, you can split a slice or array into two or more non-overlapping mutable slices of the original. This allows you to take multiple multiple references into an slice at once.

```rust
pub fn swap(arr: &mut [Foo], i: usize, j: usize) {
    let (low, high) = match i.cmp(&j) {
        Ordering::Less => (i, j),
        Ordering::Greater => (j, i),
        Ordering::Equal => return,
    };
    
    let (a, b) = arr.split_at_mut(high);
    
    std::mem::swap(&mut a[low], &mut b[0]);
}
```